# FailedAttachVolume error on Kubernetes with StorageOS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to setup a high availability cluster with storageOS.Literally i want to replicate volumes between nodes and if a node down my statefull application should start on new node with last state.

I have 1 Master and 2 Slave nodes on bare metal(virtualbox).I succesfully installed storageos with helm according to those docs: https://docs.storageos.com/docs/platforms/kubernetes/install/1.13

I can reach the web gui of storageos on browser and everything seems like fine.I also create storageclass succesfully.

I try to create a persistent volume claim and bind to a pod.After pvc and pod created , pv is succesfully produce and bound to claim.I chech it from browser and there is 1 replica and 1 master persistent volume on nodes.There is no problem until here.

when i poweroff the node of pod and restart the pod on the other node , the pod stucks on container creating state.Describe command gives that results:

**Warning FailedAttachVolume  23s   attachdetach-controller  Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-0b2a1dbf-62e4-11e9-8b86-0800278a3f7b" Volume is already used by pod(s) nginx, nginx-6779c9f48b-g2825**

I follow this guide and the pod must start on the other node with same state:
https://docs.storageos.com/docs/platforms/kubernetes/firstvolume/

I check this diretory on nodes"/var/lib/storageos/volumes" and pods and i can see the volumes in the one node (which has the persistent volume) but i can not see any volumes on the other node.

I tried:
Change pv reclaim policy
A little try with openebs but same issue
I try this troubleshooting result is same: https://docs.storageos.com/docs/platforms/kubernetes/troubleshoot/volumes#pod-in-pending-because-of-mount-error (i try only for docker i do not know how to enable MountPropagation on kubernetes)
I tried waiting for 15-20 minute but error state still same
I tried with 1 master and 3 slave node result is same

Secret and Cluster

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "storageos-api"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "storageos"
type: "kubernetes.io/storageos"
data:
  # echo -n '<secret>' | base64
  apiUsername: c3RvcmFnZW9z
  apiPassword: c3RvcmFnZW9z
---
apiVersion: "storageos.com/v1"
kind: "StorageOSCluster"
metadata:
  name: "example-storageos"
  namespace: "default"
spec:
  secretRefName: "storageos-api"
  secretRefNamespace: "default"
---
PVC and Pod
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mpvc
  labels:
    storageos.com/replicas: "1"
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: fast
spec:
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
   requests:
     storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/
          name: v1
  volumes:
    - name: v1
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: mpvc

The pod must start on the other node when a node fails but cannot bind the same volume on new node
```

Comment: Does it work without powering node down? Can you try cordoning the node and then restart pod - does it work then?

Comment: Yes i can reuse the same volume if i start the failed node.

Comment: how long do you wait after stopping the the pod node ? This error happens to me sometimes in ec2, i juste have to wait a few minutes before the volume is reattached to the new instance.

Comment: It is not automatically reattach to other node.I decided to use longhorn instead of this i suggest:
https://github.com/rancher/longhorn